# Python: global name i not defined (faulty?) error

Tags: python, class

for a couple of days I've been trying to solve this issue I'm having without any success. Most of the code was given to me, I'm supposed to make it more "object oriented".

it worked just fine before I made a class out of it.

The error I'm given so far is:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1399, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Users\oliver.andersson\Documents\pythonprog\kap21ovn1.py", line 45, in getfile
filnamn = namn.get() 
NameError: global name 'namn' is not defined
```

but I'm sure that's not the only thing wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.scrolledtext import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):

        root.title('Min texteditor')            
        frame = tk.Frame(root, bg = '#f0f0f0')  
        frame.grid()                            


        tk.Label(frame, text = 'Editera textfiler/Pythonfiler',
                 font = ('Arial', 16, 'normal')).grid(
                     row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 40)


        tk.Label(frame, text = 'Fil: ', font = ('Arial', 12, 'normal')).grid(
            row = 1, column = 0, sticky = tk.E)
        namn = tk.Entry(frame, width = 40)
        namn.grid(row = 1, column = 1, columnspan = 5, sticky = tk.W)


        openbutton = tk.Button(frame, text = 'Öppna', command = self.getfile)
        openbutton.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = tk.W)

        saveButton = tk.Button(frame, text = 'Spara', command = self.savefile)
        saveButton.grid(row = 2, column = 3, sticky = tk.W)

        saveasButton = tk.Button(frame, text = 'Spara som...', command = self.saveas)
        saveasButton.grid(row = 2, column = 4, sticky = tk.W)

        exitButton = tk.Button(frame, text = 'Avsluta', command = root.destroy)
        exitButton.grid(row = 2, column = 6, sticky = tk.E)


        tk.Label(frame, text = ' ',
                 font = ('Arial', 14, 'normal')).grid(row = 3, column = 0)


        textruta = ScrolledText(frame, heigh = 30, width = 80)
        textruta.grid(row = 4, column = 0, columnspan = 40)

    def getfile(self):

        filnamn = namn.get() 

        if not filnamn: 
            filnamn = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = (('Pythonfiler',
                                                          '*.py'),))
        if filnamn:
            try:
                fil = open(filnamn, 'r', encoding = 'utf-8')
                rader = fil.read()
            except:
                tk.messagebox.showerror('Filfel', 'Kunde inte öppna fil')
            else:
                namn.delete(0, tk.END)          
                namn.insert(0, filnamn)         
                textruta.delete(1.0,tk.END) 
                textruta.insert(1.0, rader) 

            finally:
                try:            
                    fil.close()
                except:
                    pass

    def savefile(self):

        rader = textruta.get(1.0, tk.END) 
        filnamn = namn.get()             

        if filnamn:
            try:
                fil = open(filnamn, 'w', encoding = 'utf-8')
                fil.write(rader)
            except:
                tk.messagebox.showerror('Filfel', 'Kunde inte spara fil')
            else:
                fil.close()

    def saveas(self):

        filnamn = tk.filedialog.asksaveasfile(
            filetypes = (('Alla filer', '*.*'),))

        if filnamn:
            namn.delete(0, tk.END)
            namn.insert(0, filnamn)
            savefile()

master = tk.Tk()
a = App(master)
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP is asking us to debug their code for them

Answer (score 4):

Your variable `namn` is only defined inside the `init` function. If you want it to be usable across the object, use `self.namn`.

This also applies to all variables you want to use in different methods.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing all occurrences of `namn` with `self.namn` as it needs to be a member of your object.